# Is it possible to drag row outside kendo grid?

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, angular-dragdrop, kendo-draggable

I'm filling up the kendo grid with a couple of rows and want to implement **drag/drop functionality between the grid and other html components**.

I can find a lot of resources telling how to drag/drop/sort rows inside a grid, even from one grid to another grid, but nothing really for outside the grid to another component.

*Does kendo ui-grid even support this?*

**One way I can think is** - make the entire grid draggable and when drag starts get currently selected row data and use that on drop. But that's not really a very clean way to do it. I'll even need to make a custom drag image in this case.

Any other suggestions?

Comment: How is that not very clean? Make the `tbody` of the grid draggable, define a visible element when dragging, and define the drop target. If you look at Kendo's own code, this is exactly how the implementation of draggable rows within it's grid is implemented.

Comment: Yup, didn't realize earlier.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the kendoDropTarget() method to assign another html element as the target. For example here is a grid and an HTML textarea:

```
<div id="grid"></div>
<textarea id="dropHere" rows="3" cols="50"></textarea>

$("#grid table tbody > tr").kendoDraggable({
    group: "gridGroup",
    threshold: 100,
    hint: function(e) {
        return $('<div class="k-grid k-widget"><table><tbody><tr>' + e.html() + '</tr></tbody></table></div>');
    }
});

$("#dropHere").kendoDropTarget({
    group: "gridGroup",
    drop: function(e) { 
        e.draggable.hint.hide();

        var txt = '';
        $(e.draggable.element[0]).find("td").each(function(idx, td){
          txt += $(td).text() + '\n';
        });
        e.dropTarget.text(txt);
    }
});
```

> **[DEMO](http://dojo.telerik.com/@ezanker/AZolI)**

Comment: thanks for your great example. I was wondering if its possible to keep adding rows without loosing the previous dragged rows? As in having more than one row info blocks in the text area.